# Sign git commits in Linux with X.509 certificates

Tags: linux, git, cryptography, pkcs#11, electronic-signature

It's been long enough since git permits its users to sign commits using GPG.

If we want instead to sign commits using [X.509 certificates and S/MIME](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/x509_signed_commits/), there's [smimesign](https://github.com/github/smimesign) utility that runs smoothly under Windows and Mac.

However, under Linux things get more messier, especially if we want to use a cryptographic token. It seems that if we want to use an X.509 certificate stored in a PIV card for example to sign commits, we need to use some heavy workarounds [(workarounds that involve using : gnupg, gpgsm, gpg-agent, scdaemon, gnupg-pkcs11-scd... etc)](https://sztsian.github.io/2022/02/20/Using-PKCS11-Token-With-GPG.html) in order to make it happen.

Is there a simple (simple to deploy in a corporate environment) known way to sign Git commits using something like PKCS#11 under Linux?

Comment: I did manage to sign commits with `gpgsm`, basically following [this blog post](https://enjoi.dev/posts/2021-09-30-signing-git-commits-using-s-mime-x509-certificates/). This was with a certificate exported from Entrust, not stored on a security key though...

Comment: Yes it's quite easy and straightforward to use an exported PFX certificate. However when using a security token other than an OpenPGP compatible card (PIV card, Yubikey,...etc) it gets way more messier.

Comment: I will also upport @RyanB. 

I also have a token with key-pair/certificate and want to use it. 

Meintoned paths don't route me to useful results.

Comment: @Alexander I'm starting to think the only way is to create a fork of the smimesign utility under Linux. Anyone interested?

Comment: I'll try to join and help you.